# Unable to remote to a machine running Powershell 5.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-5.0

I've come across a strange error when trying to use `Invoke-Command` or `Enter-PSSession` when the destination is running WMF 5.0 (April Preview or August pre-Release).

I haven't been able to find any reference to this on Google so I suspect it's a local/network configuration issue but I'm unsure how to track it down.

The account in question has Local Administrator permissions on both machines (Domain Group is added on both) and I can locally run any and all commands on the destination.  Remote access in the opposite direction results in the same error (also running 5.0.10514).

--- Output sanitized of identifiable information and formatting adjusted to wrap better ---

```
# user@HOST | [2015-09-09 Wed 08:18]
 C:\Windows>invoke-command -computer test {$psversiontable.psversion}

Major  Minor  Build  Revision PSComputerName
-----  -----  -----  -------- --------------
4      0      -1     -1       test

# user@HOST | [2015-09-09 Wed 08:18]
 C:\Windows>enter-pssession -computer test

[test]: PS C:\Users\user\Documents> exit

# user@HOST | [2015-09-09 Wed 08:19]
 C:\Windows>invoke-command -computer test {$psversiontable.psversion}

Major  Minor  Build  Revision PSComputerName
-----  -----  -----  -------- --------------
5      0      10514  6        test

# user@HOST | [2015-09-09 Wed 08:37]
 C:\Windows>enter-pssession -computer test
enter-pssession : The term 'Measure-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ enter-pssession -computer test
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Measure-Object:String) [Enter-PSSession], 
      CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

# user@HOST | [2015-09-09 Wed 08:38]
 C:\Windows>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your powershell session with elevated privileges (eventhough it's an Administrator accout)?

Is it working if you use a FQDN instead of the simple name? It's a known issue in some of the builds if you're using a simple name for the target.

There might be some restrictions on the commands available, if the endpoint is restricted somehow. The Measure-Object is one of the required methods needed to run in the session when using enter-pssession. This might be your issue; though hard to guess without details of your setup.

Some details on restricting commands and locking down methods in remoting:
https://www.petri.com/powershell-remoting-restricting-user-commands

There are some more details about delegated administration and proxy functions:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/04/03/use-delegated-administration-and-proxy-functions.aspx

If your target is a container, you might need to configure it properly:

https://www.petri.com/managing-windows-server-containers-with-powershell-managing-containers

Hope this helps you debugging and get remoting up working:)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix the issue.  Tried with Elevated and with FQDN but both still get the `Measure-Object` error.  However if I uninstall the WMF 5 release (so that I revert to WMF4) remoting has no issues.  Also remoting from WMF5 to 4 works, the only error is when the destination is 5.

Comment: Any active session configration files which might run when you're remoting into this machine? You could try unregistring the default session configuration and re-enabling PSRemoting on the WMF5 target. Perhaps that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. In my case, using the FQDN of the server didn't fix the problem. 
Someone posted about a problem caused by the PSModulePath variable.

- RDP to the remote server and check the current value of $env:PSModulePath
- If the path includes UNCs replace them with the name of a mapped drive (e.g. replace \myserver\public\docs with z:\docs, where z is mapped to \myserver\public)

This worked for me